# How to add .phtml file in another .phtml file in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, customer-account, customer-address

I want to show the contents file:

```
frontend\RWD\default\template\customer/address/edit.phtml
```

inside the file:

```
frontend\RWD\default\template\customer/account/dashboard.phtml.
```

I insert this code into the file `dashboard.phtml`

```
<? php
    $ block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
        ->setTemplate('customer/address/edit.phtml')
        ->toHtml();
    echo $ block; 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that directly from `dashboard.phtml` file. This change should be applied as a layout update. This will give you the start.

File : `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <customer_account_index>
        <remove name="customer_account_dashboard" />
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/address_edit" name="customer_address_edit" template="customer/address/edit.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_index>
</layout>
```

The code first remove the current dashboard content and then insert edit section into the dashboard content section.

Answer (score 2):

To get address edit form in customer dashboard page. You can do that by layout. Try below code in your local.xml  file.

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/address_edit" name="customer_address_edit" template="customer/address/edit.phtml"/>    
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

To get this in phtml file

```
<?php 
      $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/address_edit')->setTemplate('customer/address/edit.phtml')->toHtml(); 
     echo $block; 
?>
```

Comment: Using `Mage::app()->getLayout` directly in .phtml is not part of best practices. You need to use `$this->getChildHtml('identifier')` instead of this.